# Best Shape for Creating a Liquid Vortex

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, vortex

I am trying to create a vortex in a closed tube, and I am wondering if there are any resources with research on what shape would be most effective for creating this vortex. Literally any shape, paddle, whisk fan, just which would create the strongest/fastest vortex and equal angular velocities. If the viscosity matters, I would be trying to induce this vortex in water.

Comment: For between $20-$40 USD, a magnetic stirrer can be purchased that creates a controllable vortex in a beaker. I've seen them on Amazon.